# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Below is the code I am working with.  I'm trying to fix an error with a map not displaying in all browsers.

In dev tools (chrome), I'm getting a `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined` error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//google map

function loadGoogleMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom:      14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map")[0], mapOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var count = 0;
    $.each(dealers, function(ind,dealer){

        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(dealer.lat,dealer.lng)
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map:      map,
            title:    dealer.post_title,
            icon:     icons[count]
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:'<div class="infowindow">'+
                        '<strong>' + dealer.post_title + '</strong><br/>' +
                        '<address>' +
                            dealer.address1 + '<br/>' +
                            dealer.city + ', ' + dealer.state + '<br/>' +
                        '</address>' +
                        dealer.phone + '<br/>' +
                        (dealer.url != '' ? '<a href="' + dealer.url+ '">Dealer Website</a><br/>' : '') +
                        (dealer.email != '' ? '<a href="mailto:' + dealer.email+ '">Email Dealer</a><br/>' : '') +
                        '<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=&daddr=' + dealer.address + ', ' + dealer.city + ', ' + dealer.state + '" target="_blank">Get Directions</a>'+
                    '</div>'
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

        // add event listener to distributor list
        $('#distributors-list li:eq(' + count + ')').click(function(){
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

        bounds.extend(point);

        count++;
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
loadGoogleMap();

// reuse fancybox loading icon script

var loadingTimer, loadingFrame = 1;

var locator_animate_loading = function() {
    locatorLoading = $('#ajax-loading-overlay');
    if (!locatorLoading.is(':visible')){
        clearInterval(loadingTimer);
        return;
    }
    $(locatorLoading).css('background-position', '0 ' + (loadingFrame * -40) + 'px');

    loadingFrame = (loadingFrame + 1) % 12;
};

$('form.distributor-search').submit(function(e){
    locatorLoading = $('#ajax-loading-overlay');
    locatorLoading.show();
    loadingTimer = setInterval(locator_animate_loading, 66);
    $('#locator-content').load(site_url + '/graceports/find-a-distributor?ajax=1&address=' + encodeURIComponent($('#address_search').val()) + ' #ajax-contents', function() {
        // load updated list of dealers
        $('#locator-content').append('<script src="' + site_url + '/js/dealers.php?address=' + encodeURIComponent($('#address_search').val()) + '"></script>');
        loadGoogleMap();
        locatorLoading.hide();
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    $.get(site_url + '/cms/wp-content/themes/grace/inc/latlng-to-zip.php?latlng=' + encodeURIComponent(position.coords.latitude + ' ' + position.coords.longitude), function(data){
        $('#address_search').val(data);
        $('form.distributor-search').trigger('submit');
    });
});

});
```

Comment: Seriously though, where are you loading the google maps API?

Comment: Yeah, you need to load the Google Maps API - http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true

Comment: I've inherited this code and that was my question as well.  The locator.js file (above) is referenced in the wordpress template file (find-a-distributor.php)

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait until google has loaded before running your scripts. Put this somewhere in your document:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//google map



function loadGoogleMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom:      14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map")[0], mapOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' +
    'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

}

```
    var count = 0;
    $.each(dealers, function(ind,dealer){

        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(dealer.lat,dealer.lng)
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map:      map,
            title:    dealer.post_title,
            icon:     icons[count]
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:'<div class="infowindow">'+
                        '<strong>' + dealer.post_title + '</strong><br/>' +
                        '<address>' +
                            dealer.address1 + '<br/>' +
                            dealer.city + ', ' + dealer.state + '<br/>' +
                        '</address>' +
                        dealer.phone + '<br/>' +
                        (dealer.url != '' ? '<a href="' + dealer.url+ '">Dealer Website</a><br/>' : '') +
                        (dealer.email != '' ? '<a href="mailto:' + dealer.email+ '">Email Dealer</a><br/>' : '') +
                        '<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=&daddr=' + dealer.address + ', ' + dealer.city + ', ' + dealer.state + '" target="_blank">Get Directions</a>'+
                    '</div>'
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

        // add event listener to distributor list
        $('#distributors-list li:eq(' + count + ')').click(function(){
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

        bounds.extend(point);

        count++;
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
loadGoogleMap();

// reuse fancybox loading icon script

var loadingTimer, loadingFrame = 1;

var locator_animate_loading = function() {
    locatorLoading = $('#ajax-loading-overlay');
    if (!locatorLoading.is(':visible')){
        clearInterval(loadingTimer);
        return;
    }
    $(locatorLoading).css('background-position', '0 ' + (loadingFrame * -40) + 'px');

    loadingFrame = (loadingFrame + 1) % 12;
};

$('form.distributor-search').submit(function(e){
    locatorLoading = $('#ajax-loading-overlay');
    locatorLoading.show();
    loadingTimer = setInterval(locator_animate_loading, 66);
    $('#locator-content').load(site_url + '/graceports/find-a-distributor?ajax=1&address=' + encodeURIComponent($('#address_search').val()) + ' #ajax-contents', function() {
        // load updated list of dealers
        $('#locator-content').append('<script src="' + site_url + '/js/dealers.php?address=' + encodeURIComponent($('#address_search').val()) + '"></script>');
        loadGoogleMap();
        locatorLoading.hide();
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    $.get(site_url + '/cms/wp-content/themes/grace/inc/latlng-to-zip.php?latlng=' + encodeURIComponent(position.coords.latitude + ' ' + position.coords.longitude), function(data){
        $('#address_search').val(data);
        $('form.distributor-search').trigger('submit');
    });
});
```

});

Comment: I'm not sure if the google API is loading within my PHP file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=68363563158541532831

Comment: it is not - using the snippet I pasted above should help you load it

Comment: what happens when you type in `window.google` in the javascript console? make sure you are placing your custom code inside of the initialize block. are you seeing any JS errors logged in the console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined locator.js:11
loadGoogleMap locator.js:11
(anonymous function) locator.js:63
c jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
p.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
b.extend.ready jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
H jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3

Comment: The callback is named 'initialize' - you need to run your code within the initialize function in order for this to work. `initialize = function(){ //your code }` If you are already doing this somewhere, please share with me the full code source for locator.js so I can help you pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Here is the entire locator.js code: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00824015146415284489